# Replace SQL Server 2000 with 2008 same name

Tags: sql-server

We are replacing an old SQL Server 2000 box with new hardware and SQL 2008. If we name the new server the same as the old will ODBC connections still work? What about replication and linked servers?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the new server the same name, configure logins and roles the same way and attach (or restore) the databases to it, yes, connections *should* work (possibly with some upgrade to the client SQL connectivity software, depending on the O.S. used).

Replication and linked servers will need to be reconfigured from scratch on the new server, though.